# How to copy every file in a directory except those with 2 different extensions?

Tags: bash, shell, copy, command

I want to copy all the files in the current directory to directory "folder_1", except for those ending in .txt and .png

I've tried the following:

```
shopt -s extglob 
cp !(*.txt) folder_1
```

But I need to make this more general to include png as well

Comment: `!(*.txt|*.png)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cp !(*.txt|*.png) folder_1
```

[bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized. In the following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a ‘|’. Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> ...
>
> !(pattern-list)
>
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns.